# url not working properly in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

When click on the Register link. It will not go to the register.html page. What is the wrong in this.

**app.js**

```
.when('/login/:register/', {
templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
controller: 'RegisterController'
});
```

**login.html**

```
<button href="#/login/:register/" class="button button-block button-positive activated">Register</button>
```

Comment: login page will display.after that click on the Register button. It will not redirect the Register page

Comment: no slash will come after :register    change /login/:register/ to /login/:register.     :register is a  $stateParam also make sure to pass some values to :register

Comment: I changed like you said. but not working

Comment: But, I did not create RegisterCotroller until this.

Answer (score 0):

`:register` is a parameter in the route.

As you want to use as simple URL remove `:` from the route.

**app.js**

```
.when('/login/register/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
    controller: 'RegisterController'
});
```

**login.html**, You need to use `anchor` if you want to use `href`

```
<a ng-href="#/login/register/">Register</a>
```

OR,

```
<button ng-click="redirect()">Register</button>
```

In controller use

```
$scope.redirect= function(){
    $loaction.path('/login/register/')
}
```

Comment: But, I did not create RegisterCotroller until this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use anchor tag instead of button. I mean

```
<a href="#/login/:register/">Register</a>
```

Comment: But, I did not create RegisterCotroller until this.

Comment: Are u looking for nested view ? If so then better use ui-router instead of  ng-router

Comment: How to use that. can you fixed this problem

Comment: Could u please look into this plunker,might help u. https://plnkr.co/edit/vzxGO6HNxYIPZbdZyOJt?p=preview

Comment: For nested view,have a look into this plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/ac8i8MSUKdXIdTU3eCpL?p=preview

Comment: Have created for first plunk.

Comment: But. I created separate file for `registerController`. Is that ok right.

Comment: yep..Just include that js file to ur index page.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use ui router, it uses state instead of url using ui-sref,
if you have time and you need better handling over rouuting, tru ui router.

Comment: how to do that. can you give me some help pls

Comment: this is an advancement of angular ngRouter, try this tutorial. https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/